# Why my VPS not accepting connections from outside?

Tags: apache, windows-server-2008, vps

I have a windows server 2008 VPS with no software installed on it and the only way to connect to it is remote desktop connection so I have to prepare it from scratch.
I installed apache server on it BUT after installing apache:

**ON THE VPS:**

- when i go to localhost i get the "it works!" Home page so this sounds ok.
- and "Netstat -a" results shows port 80 ok as following:
  [image]

**From other pc**
 - can't go to homepage via browser.

NOTE: I don't have a domain but i wish to access via browser using the VPS ip.

Comment: How are you expecting it to work? Are you expecting DNS to work? Are you expecting port 80 to be forwarded to it? Or what?

Comment: I wish to write my ip in the browser to open the server public_html directory, or download a file from it.

Comment: When you say "my ip", what IP are you talking about?

Comment: I mean My VPS IP that I use to connect via "remote desktop connection"

Comment: Okay, so what happens when you point a browser at that IP? (First, check firewall settings.)

Comment: there an exception for apache in the firewall and when i point to the IP in the browser it keeps loading and then nothing. and tried to ping the ip but always request timeout and 100% loss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56165/discussion-between-medo-ampir-and-david-schwartz).

Answer (score 0):

nevermind guys it worked now.
I just added port 80 to firewall. I thought that if the port stats is Listening then it is ok but I found out that I have to add the port to the firewall too.